# Docker desktop on Parrot os 5.2 electro ara version

Tags: docker, parrot-os

i currently run this version of parrot Os in a Virtual Machine. Anyone can explain me step by step to run Docker desktop here, because i try to install with the docker docs doesn't work.
and i try to install some dependencies to run .deb package and still same issue doesn't work to.

any please assist me

Run docker desktop successfully in parrot Os

Comment: That's a Linux distribution?  I'd recommend not running Docker Desktop at all.  Also, since you're running it in a VM already, Docker Desktop will have trouble starting up its embedded Linux VM.  "How do I install Docker" isn't really a programming-related question, though, and another Stack Exchange site like [unix.se] might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Docker Desktop is a linux VM itself , it might be better to install Docker Engine in your Parrot VM. The Debian docs state that you should select the Bookworm version. I find no instructions regarding Ara there. Download by package is less error prone than by the shell command line. You still may encounter issues. It is, to state it technically ' a right palava'. This is where to start: https://download.docker.com/debian/dists  then select bookworm/pool/stable and your architecture to see the packages.